# How to get started with developing for OnsenUI?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui

I have the setup ready and all is working fine but I am having difficulty grabbing the concept on navigator,  and cannot find many tutorials. I found this 
https://github.com/iampeterbanjo/hello-onsenui-sliding_menu_navigator/tree/master/app
But since there was no explanation it is hard to grab the idea and use it in other project.
Also, what are the limitations with using OnsenUI except for those which are applicable on native vs hybrid apps.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to do as follows:

1. Read their [getting started](http://onsenui.io/guide/getting_started.html) and [guide](http://onsenui.io/guide/overview.html).
2. You can find some OnsenUI templates code and explanation [here](http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/en/sampleapp/).
3. To understand how to use OnsenUI components, pleas read [here](http://onsenui.io/guide/components.html).
4. If you face any difficulty during ur development with OnsenUI, you can post the questions here in stackoverflow using "onsen-ui"
   tag. The OnsenUI teams will help you out.

Good luck.